# Correct @If syntax in the blade view for Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, html, if-statement, laravel-blade

This is my code in the blade view. My purpose is for this specific HTML to show up only if the authenticated user's email address matches in the if condition. Please check below, it is currently not working as it should be

```
@if ('{{ Auth::user()->email }}' == 'evangelism.sec@gmail.com')
          <li> 
           <a href="{{ URL::route('UploadsHome') }}"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>File Uploads</a>
          </li>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use without `'` quotes and without `{{` brackets just use `Auth::user()->email` or better `\Auth::user()->email`.

```
@if (\Auth::user()->email == 'evangelism.sec@gmail.com')
  <li> 
   <a href="{{ URL::route('UploadsHome') }}"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>File Uploads</a>
  </li>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work:

```
@if (Auth::user()->email == 'evangelism.sec@gmail.com')
  //your code after authentication
@else
  //user not logged in
@endif
```